# How can I switch toggle Input.GetKeyDown in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DroidMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject droid;

    private void Start()
    {
        droid.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            droid.transform.position = droid.transform.position - transform.forward;
            droid.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I want that once I click on D it will show the Droid and also when I move the camera(transform) the droid will follow the camera.

And when I click once again on D set the droid active to false so each time I click on D it will toggle between SetActive false and true.

Comment: droid.SetActive(!droid.active);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For toggling an object you should use something like this. PSEUDO

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {

            droid.enabled = !droid.enabled;
        }
```

This will allow you to toggle your gameObject each time you press the button D.

In KeyDown

```
droid.transform.position = droid.transform.position - transform.forward;
```

This will work only once (One Frame). So you can use a bool or check if your gameObject is active to follow your camera. In Update you can use the following

```
if (droid.activeInHierarchy == true) // or you can use a bool here
        {
            droid.transform.position = droid.transform.position - transform.forward;

        }
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: When i'm doing droid.transform.position = droid.transform.position - transform.forward; and then pressing D many times each time when the droid is setactive true again the droid is getting closer and closer to the player. And i want to keep in the same original distance. And the droid is not following the camera movement.  I forgot to mention that transform is FirstPersonCharacter and when i move around the camera that is attached to the FirstPersonCharacter i want the droid to follow the camera move.

Comment: It seems like you are only moving the droid in the opposite of your FirstPersonCharacter's direction (transform.forward). To move it to the camera position, you need to move along the Vector from the droid to the camera (droid.transform.position - transform.position).By the way, take a look at Unity's [Navigation](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation/navigation-overview?playlist=17105), it might cover your needs already.